# Video chat client using HTML5, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, videochat

Is there any existing framework/plugin that provides video chat capability in any web application using HTML 5 and JavaScript (Client side technoligies)?

Comment: This should be meta question, although don't want to down vote, see this http://www.magnoliyan.com/........

Answer (score 5):

I will try to explain shortly what do you need to create a live video chat.
**1.** You need to decide wich streaming protocols you will use. There a lot of streaming protocols (HLS, DASH, RTMP, RTSP, Smooth, HDS).
It is nearly impossible to support all devices with only one protocol.
[HLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) - is only way to stream video via html 5.
[DASH](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-DASH) - used only for browsers which support MSE.
and etc.
But you can pack your videos in several protocols on the fly to support more devices.
**2.** You need to configure video streaming server to stream your videos.
You can use free video servers like:
[NGINX](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/)
[Nimble Streamer](https://wmspanel.com/nimble)
and etc.
If you do not want to spend your time to configure this servers you can use  pay video server that will help you to encode, pack and stream your videos.
Example:
[Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/streaming/live-video-streaming) 
**3.** You need to chose video player to stream your videos. There a lot of html 5 video players which support flash playback.
Example:
[Flowplayer](https://flowplayer.org/)
[JWplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/)
Also there a lot of absolutely free video players like:
[Video.js](http://videojs.com/)
[MedialElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)
[Dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki)
and etc.
So, if you decided to use HLS and DASH you need to chose player which supports these protocols like:
flowplayer - support HLS and DASH
or dash.js for DASH and video.js for HLS.
You can easily customize most of these video players.